# Find bipartial subgraph such that sum of edge lengths is maximum

Tags: algorithms, graphs, greedy-algorithms, bipartite-graph

Let there be graph $G = (V, E)$. $G$ has neither loops nor parallel arcs.

$V = A \cup B, \, A \neq \emptyset, \, B \neq \emptyset, A \cap B = \emptyset$

For simplicity's sake, let's consider $G$ is directed.

$\forall \ e \in E \ \, e.tail \in A, \, e.head \in B, \, e.length \in (\mathbb{Z} \cap [1, 100]) \cup -\infty \\
\forall \ a \in A, \, b \in B \ \ \exists! \ e \in E: e = (a, b)$

**The goal is** to develop an algorithm that finds a bipartite subgraph such that $\sum \limits_{e \in E} e.length$ **is maximum possible**.

For example, let graph $G$ be defined as following:
[image]

In this case, the correct solution is:
[image]

Is there an other approach besides greedy algorithm (take $a$, pick the best $b$ [such that $b = b_0, b_0: (a, b_0).length = \max_{b \in B} \ (a, b).length$] for this $a$, remove $b$ from $B$, take the next $a$)? The algorithm should run in polynomial time.

Comment: Evaluate *all* combination, pick best?

Comment: Please ask one question per post, not three questions.  Criterion c doesn't make sense, as there might be no way to pick a subgraph that satisfies both requirements (both things you want to maximize).  Do you want a polynomial-time algorithm?  If so, you should specify that.

Comment: The problem statement and the example do not match. In the problem statement you specified that you were looking for an induced subgraph. The graph in the example is not an induced subgraph. It seemed in the example, you are looking for an injective assignment. Can you check which variant you are really looking for and update correspondingly.

Answer (score 0):

The way to make $\sum_{e \in E} e.\text{length}$ be maximum is to take all the edges with positive length, i.e., set $E'=\{e \in E \mid e.\text{length} > 0\}$.  Since your graph is already bipartite, this subgraph will be as well.